# find amount all the 3-digit numbers

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The problem states:

find an amount of 3-digit numbers with digits that are not the power of cube (as far as I understand $8$ can not be taken as it is $2^3$ I am also **not sure** about $1^3 = 1$) and also these numbers have to have digits that go in descending order. If take the combinatory formula it is gonna be "number of combinations w/o repeation" (because I also have to write final calсulus using the formula).

it is also clear that there are 3 sequences of digits

- First position - 6 digits ( I excluded $0$, $1$ and $8$)
- Second position - 7 digits (I excluded $1$ and $8$)
- Thrid position - 7 digits (I excluded $1$ and $8$)

still not sure how to arrange "in descending order" part

Comment: Does descending order include the case of equality as in the example $100$ or $211$?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I know what *amount* means and how it is used in this context, but why do you think it is so despicable?

Comment: @ArsenBerk, well, actually the problem states nothing about repeating digits only emphases "__decreasing__", so I think I was wrong about non-repeating combinations and they are implicitly allowed

Comment: @TheSimpliFire, would you want "number of numbers" there? :)

Comment: By the way I have written a code and $432, 532, 542, 543, 632, 642, 643, 652, 653, 654, 732, 742, 743, 752, 753, 754, 762, 763, 764, 765, 932, 942, 943, 952, 953, 954, 962, 963, 964, 965, 972, 973, 974, 975, 976$ are the numbers without repetition in descending order and there are $35$ of them (they don't include $0$,$1$ and $8$).

Comment: @ArsenBerk, I did this too, but still not sure which formula I should pick out and use (combinatory one). And how to explain how to find decreasing numbers :( (formally)

Comment: It is $\binom 73$. This is because the order is automatically determined when you choose three numbers from $2,3,4,5,6,7$ or $9$.

Comment: Well, I always forgot about the argument that @mathlove stated... If you choose $3$ numbers from the $7$, there is only $1$ way to order them in descending order. So the answer simply becomes $\binom{7}{3}$. It is the formal way actually.

Comment: By the way, note that $0^3=0$. This is why we exclude $0$ as a digit.

Answer (score 3):

Without repetition, the answer is $\binom 73=35$.

This is because the order is automatically determined when you choose three numbers from $2,3,4,5,6,7$ or $9$.

Answer (score 1):

First, let $abc$ be a $3-$digit number where $a \ne 0,1,8$, $b \ne 0,1,8$ and $c \ne 0,1,8$.

Now, notice that since $a \ne 0,1,8$ and $b \ne 0,1,8$, there are $7 \cdot 7 = 49$ of $2$-digit numbers $ab$. Now assuming equality is not included in descending order, we can eliminate the cases where $a=b$ and there are $7$ of them (namely $22$, $33$, $44$, $55$, $66$, $77$, $99$). And among $49-7=42$ numbers, in half of them $a < b$ and in half of them $b < a$ (we can use symmetry because $0$ is already eliminated so all of those $42$ numbers are valid $2$-digit numbers). So there are $21$ numbers here only with the condition $a > b$.

By using the same argument, we can say that there are $21$ numbers only with condition $b > c$. However, in this case, we are also counting the cases where $b = 9$ and there are $6$ of them so we have to exclude them. Also notice that we have to exclude the case where $a = 9$ and $b = 2$ because $c \ne 0,1$. So there are $7$ cases to exclude and the answer becomes $21+21-7 = 35$.

However, I don't know if an argument like this one works in for example $4$-digit numbers. And this is not a "formal" way neither.

Answer (score 1):

Another more explicit way than directly giving combinations.

I take strict descending order and digits $9,7,6,5,4,3,2$ ($0,1,8$ are assumed to be cubes). we have $abc$ with $ a\gt b\gt c$

$$\begin{array}aa=9\Rightarrow 5+4+3+2+1\text{ possible numbers }\\a=7\Rightarrow 4+3+2+1\text{ possible numbers }\\a=6\Rightarrow 3+2+1\text{ possible numbers }\\a=5\Rightarrow 2+1\text{ possible numbers }\\a=4\Rightarrow 1\text{ possible number: 432  }\\a=3\Rightarrow\text{no possible numbers }\end{array}$$

Thus there are $15+10+6+3+1=35$ numbers